# can imacros change html tag values

Tags: html, tags, imacros

I want imacros to type 'testing' in a particular form.
when I go to a website and try to use this imacros line:

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=NAME:destination CONTENT=testing

It's finding this tag:

```
<input style="position: relative; vertical-align: top;" dir="auto" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" class="auto-complete route-call-to tt-input" name="destination" type="text"></input>
```

the thing is.. imacros will find this tag but the text will not be entered unless I go to inspector and change this tag to this:

```
<input name="destination" type="text"></input>
```

I'm wondering how I could get this resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the html tag value as you'd like, try something like this:

```
URL GOTO=javascript:{window.document.getElementsByName("destination")[0].outerHTML='<input<SP>name="destination"<SP>type="text"></input>';undefined;}
```